# PayPal IPN simulator - how to generate INVALID response?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using [Paypal IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)  to test changes. I'm trying to generate an `INVALID` response.

I select

`Transaction type:`  Cart Checkout

`payment_status:`  Denied, Failed or Expired.

However all of these generate a notification call with response `VERIFIED`

**update** didn't [read close enough](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). Documentation says: PayPal sends a single word back, which is either VERIFIED if the message **originated with PayPal** or INVALID if there is any discrepancy with what was originally sent. So if I just browse to my IPN URL directly, I will get an INVALID response from Paypal because the call to IPN did not originate with PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your update: close, but not exactly.

IPN will return **VERIFIED** or **INVALID** depending on whether or not it recognizes the POST data you're sending as having originated from PayPal.
So yes, if you browse to your IPN URL directly and it directly POST's no data / dummy data to PayPal, then yes, we won't recognize it as having originated from us and we'll return **INVALID**.

For example, this link will return **INVALID**: 
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&dummy_data=true